# Increase node speed for every contact

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Inside my `didbeginContact` I added code like:

```
// increase node speed on each contact
CGVector thrustVector = CGVectorMake(_node.physicsBody.velocity.dx+100,
                                     _node.physicsBody.velocity.dy+100);
[_node.physicsBody applyForce:thrustVector];
```

But it is not increasing its speed on every contact with another node. It should bounce a little bit (more) for every contact.

I also tried:

```
// increase node speed on each contact
_node.physicsBody.restitution = _node.physicsBody.restitution + 0.001f;
NSLog(@"current node restitution: %f", _node.physicsBody.restitution);
```

But when the node bounces too FAST it suddenly goes through other nodes that are suppose to be walls.

But how do I properly do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying force, you might want to try applying an impulse for a more instantaneous effect:

```
[_node.physicsBody applyImpulse:thrustVector];
```

Bear in mind that you're using a vector based on the node's current velocity, so if that drops in the meantime, the impulse will be smaller too.

If the node is moving too fast, it can happen that it will pass through another body (wall) completely before the new frame is rendered, so no collision will be detected. There is a property that enables performing more expensive calculations on such fast bodies, `_node.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES`.

However, even that may not be satisfactory if you reach extreme velocities. You may have to implement some manual checking if the node is still within the edge walls' bounds in the `-(void)didSimulatePhysics` method.

Comment: I start my node by making it fall straight down. Using the first code I've shown in my question the ball suddenly goes right on initialise.

Comment: I still can't get the proper way in applying the impulse to make the node steadily go faster but with a max speed. Though usePreciseCollisionDetection makes the going out of bounds fixed, but like you said at very fast speed it still goes out.